# How does a C/C++ compiler optimize division by non-powers-of-two?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64

I've been learning a little bit of assembly, and I know that compilers can optimize.
I know that a compiler can optimize something like

```c
int i;
i /= 2;
```

to

```
; suppose i is in eax
sar eax, 1
```

Not knowing about more optimizations, I assume that

```c
int i;
i /= 3;
```

would become

```
; suppose i is in eax
xor edx, edx
mov ecx, 3
idiv ecx
```

but instead, I get an interesting chain of multiplications and shifts:

```
; copied from Compiler Explorer, number is in rsi
mov     rax, rsi
imul    rsi, rsi, 1431655766
sar     eax, 31
shr     rsi, 32
sub     esi, eax
```

How does this optimization work? Here's the link to [Compiler Explorer.](https://godbolt.org/z/xrv7TKhGc)

Comment: It does. I didn't search it up, oops

Comment: Division or multiplication by constant may be special cased for certain specific constant values, but there are also generalized algorithms to substitute for the other not special cased constant values.